# How do I adjust Unity 2D jump velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm currently following a YouTube tutorial by Jason Weimann on how to make a 2D flappy bird game in Unity. Everything has worked fine so far, until it came to the part where you write code to make the player jump and change the jump velocity. The player can jump fine, but I don't know how to change the velocity. I've tried commenting on the video for help, but haven't gotten a reply yet. I'm very new to programming and don't know much about C#. Here's my code so far:

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector2 jumpVelocity;

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = jumpVelocity;
    }
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get comfortable with c# coding.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour { 
  [SerializeField] // now you can set it from Inspector for Player script
  private Vector2 jumpVelocity;
  
  void Awake() {
    jumpVelocity = new Vector2(0f, 1f); // or set the values for x n y axes in code
  }
  void Update()
  {
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = jumpVelocity;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Velocity in 2D is a Vector unit, it have X and Y axis
So if you assign a float variable < without definitions > to the Vector2, it will cause error. You need to assign it to a Vector2. Like this

`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0f, 1f);`

Or declare a Vector2 jumpVelocity like above answer and just change

`new Vector2(0f, 1f)` to `jumpVelocity`